# Biztalk error: Exception occurred when persisting state to the database

Tags: biztalk

I am attempting to insert XML message into Biztalk message box database and I am getting the error

> Exception occurred when persisting state to the database.

I have an orchestration which needs to read this message from the message box. I have applied appropriate filter in receive port of the orchestration. Also the filter criteria is matched with the xml which I am trying to insert.

Can anybody throw some light on this problem?

Comment: There is usually a whole lot more info dumped into the Event Log when messages get suspended with this exception - please can you post the whole message? That said, the issue usually means that there are no subscribers found for this message.

Comment: I have gone into orchestration debugger and message flow view which gave me better understanding of the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. The orchestration which reads the inserted message from message box doesn't have the direct port and so when I try to insert a message in message box it doesn't find the subscriber of that message.

I have made the orchestration port as direct port and problem got resolved.

Comment: I too have faced this error where the subscriber was unenlisted, so message wasn't able to find any subscriber

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have duplicate subscriptions in your Message Box.  This is one of those errors that can happen for a number of reasons, but this is the first thing I will investigate when I encounter it.

[Here's a blog post I wrote about this situation a while ago](http://biztalktalk.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/persistenceexception/).

To check your active subscriptions, use BizTalk Administration Console, and on the 'New Query' tab, change the 'Search for' drop-down to 'Subscriptions'

Comment: Thanks Brett, my first suspection was the duplicate subscription only. However, that was not the problem. It was due to my orchestration was not listening from direct port.